# Add count as label to points in geom_count

Tags: r, ggplot2, label

I used geom_count to visualise overlaying points as sized groups, but I also want to add the actual count as a label to the plotted points, like this:

[image]
However, to achieve this, I had to create a new data frame containing the counts and use these data in geom_text as shown here:

```
#Creating two data frames
data <- data.frame(x = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4),
               y = c(1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3),
               id = c("a", "b", "b", "b", "c", 
                      "c", "d", "d", "d", "e"))
data2 <- data %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(x = mean(x), y = mean(y), count = n())

# Creating the plot
ggplot(data = data, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_count() +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(10, 15)) +
  geom_text(data = data2, 
            aes(x = x, y = y, label = count),
            color = "#ffffff")
```

Is there any way to achieve this in a more elegant way (i.e. without the need for the second data frame)? I know that you can access the count in geom_count using `..n..`, yet if I try to access this in `geom_text`, this is not working.

Comment: why do you need `data` when you have `data2`, just plot from it.

Comment: @PoGibas: this is indeed an option (which, honestly, I overlooked). Nonetheless, since the geom_count is able to do the summarising  calculation part for you, it would be neat if there was a way of also directly using this information

Comment: I understand, but my honest suggestion (personal experience) is to leave plotting for `ggplot2` and all other calculations outside `ggplot2` - data modification, cleaning, summary is done before `ggplot2`. Saves time and easier :-)

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you expecting this:

```
ggplot(data %>% 
         group_by(id) %>%
         summarise(x = mean(x), y = mean(y), count = n()), 
       aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_point(aes(size = count)) +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(10, 15)) +
  geom_text(aes(label = count),
            color = "#ffffff")
```

[image]

**update:**
If the usage of `geom_count` is must, then the expected output can be achieved using:

```
p <- ggplot(data = data, aes(x = x, y = y)) +
  geom_count() + scale_size_continuous(range = c(10, 15))
p + geom_text(data = ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]], 
              aes(x, y, label = n), color = "#ffffff")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this works indeed. Nonetheless, this still involves manually calculating the information that is readily available in the geom_count. However, I still wonder if there is any way to access this information directly and save myself the summarise step (which basically geom_count does for you).

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is indeed the kind of thing I was thinking about.

Answer (score 0):

here would be a solution for a code with discrete values

```
f<-ggplot(data = STest, aes(x = x, y = y)) + geom_count()+scale_x_discrete(labels = c("strong decrease","decrease","no change","increase","strong increase","no opinion"))+scale_y_discrete(labels = c("strong decrease","decrease","no change","increase","strong increase","no opinion"))


f + geom_text(data = ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]],aes(x, y, label = n,vjust= -2))
```

Thank you so much!

Answer (score -2):

A much easier way to change this is to use the labs() function so in this case it would be ...labs(size = "Count") + ....

That should be all you need.