# Can I plot the number count in ggplot2 using geom_text instead the size of points (geom_count)?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot a ggplot graph and instead of the size of point indicating the count, I need to plot the overlapping count number. Can you help me?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1P01.jpg

Thank you very much!

My data:

```
ID  CIM DD
1   8   8
2   8   8
3   8   4
4   4   4
5   2   2
6   8   8
7   8   8
8   8   8
9   2   2
10  2   2
11  2   4
12  4   4
13  8   4
14  2   2
15  4   4
16  4   8
17  2   4
18  16  8
19  8   16
20  16  16
21  2   4
22  16  8
23  8   8
24  8   8
25  8   8
26  4   4
27  1   2
28  4   8
29  8   8
30  2   4
31  8   8
32  2   2
33  1   2
34  4   8
35  8   8
36  16  8
37  8   8
38  4   4
39  4   8
40  4   8
41  8   8
42  8   8
43  2   2
```

I used the code below to make an overlapping count graph as shown in an image link:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/w1P01.jpg

```
breaks = c(1,2,4,8,16)
labels = as.character(breaks)
ggplot(data = Data,aes(CIM,DD)) +
geom_count()+
scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1, 32), breaks = breaks, labels =       labels,name = "CIM")+
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(1, 32), breaks = breaks, labels =      labels,name = "DD")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this example:

[Add count as label to points in geom_count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46851450/add-count-as-label-to-points-in-geom-count)

You could do the following with your data:

```
p <- ggplot(data = Data,aes(CIM,DD)) +
  geom_count(show.legend = FALSE)+
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1, 32), breaks = breaks, labels = labels,name = "CIM") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(1, 32), breaks = breaks, labels = labels,name = "DD") +
  scale_size_continuous(range = c(10, 10))

p + geom_text(data = ggplot_build(p)$data[[1]], aes(x, y, label = n), color = "#ffffff")
```

You can adjust the range in `scale_size_continuous` if you wish to vary the size of points.

Comment: Thank you very much! It`s exactly what I need! I Just adjusted the size of the points just like you said and it works perfectly!  I shared the image below to help the others! thanks a lot!

!https://imgur.com/a/DeMtism